# No Internet connection in Firefox, must end process and restart

Tags: internet

Firefox works fine for a while then slows down until there's no internet connection at all. After closing firefox and restarting (after I had to end process in system monitor) internet works fine again.

I've tried with reinstalling it again and making new profile, didn't help.

ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Seems with the new firefox update the problem is gone

Answer (score 0):

What add-ons are you using? [HTTPS-Everywhere by any chance?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959700) It seems to be causing those problems.

Comment: have no add-ons